# Enable trashes for mounted ext4 partition

Tags: mount, ext4, trash

I'd like to mount an ext4 partition with subfolders for multiple users

```
/data
  user1/
  user2/
  ...
```

just like `/home`. Thus I copied the fstab entry of the `/home` mouting,

```
UUID=...   /data    ext4    defaults    0    2
```

manually created the mount point

```
sudo mkdir /data
```

and created subfolders with the appropriate rights:

```
sudo mkdir /data/user1 && chown user1:user1 /data/user1
sudo mkdir /data/user2 && chown user2:user2 /data/user2
...
```

Though this allows the users to create files in their subfolder, **they are not able to move them to trash**.

I manually created the `lost+found` folder with no luck.

```
# ls -al /data/ | grep lost
drwx------  2 root        root        4096 Okt 15 11:55 lost+found
```

What do I need to change to enable the trash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the trash directory needs to be named in this format to make this work: .Trash-$UID
[Allow for 'Move to trash' instead of 'permanently delete' for mounted partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091885/allow-for-move-to-trash-instead-of-permanently-delete-for-mounted-partition)

#######################################################################

According to [this archlinux post](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=175468) referring to the [FreeDesktop Trash Specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/trash-spec/trashspec-latest.html) we can use trash folders for each user, that are located in the top folder

```
/data
  .Trash-<user1.uid>
  .Trash-<user2.uid>
  ...
```

and that are owned by the respective user.

```
chown user1:user1 /data/.Trash-<user1.uid>
chown user2:user2 /data/.Trash-<user2.uid>
...
```

After this modification users are able to create files, to delete files to the trash and to recover them.

**Update**: You have to re-log to make this work.

Comment: The Trash-Spec and KDE are very picky about the permissions on these files. Trash-Spec says, .Trash/ must be 1777. KDE wants .Trash/<user-id> and .Trash-<user-id> to be 700 (until a patch of Sept 2020)

Answer (score 0):

the correct format for the said trash directory is

```
.Trash-$UID

mkdir -p .Trash-$UID/{expunged,files,info}
chown $UID:$GID -Rv .Trash-$UID
chmod 750 -Rv .Trash-$UID
```

The above works for me in ubuntu, arch, and fedora
references:

[Allow for 'Move to trash' instead of 'permanently delete' for mounted partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091885/allow-for-move-to-trash-instead-of-permanently-delete-for-mounted-partition)

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Trash_management

https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=207042

Answer (score -1):

I created a script named `mktrash.sh` to `mkdir` the trash-folder.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" = "" ]; then
    echo "Parameter: <mount path> - the top directory"
    exit
fi

TRASH=$1/.Trash
UTRASH=$TRASH/$UID

echo Creating Trash Directory: $UTRASH
echo Ctrl-C to Cancel, Enter to Continue
echo You will need to enter your SUDO password for creating $TRASH
read VAR

sudo mkdir -v $TRASH
sudo chmod -v 1777 $TRASH
mkdir -v $UTRASH
chmod -v 700 $UTRASH
```

Would be nice to have this automated for any mounts.

Once the `.Trash` dir exists, new users should be added automatically as `Trash` is world writeable.